# How to dynamically pass psql variable value at runtime?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to create shortcuts for DBAs/admins in psql.
I have created some functions and queries, which give me information such as schema size in bytes, or a list of tables in order of storage used, etc. These will be used whenever an admin or DBA wants to get some info about the database.
I can run these queries naturally with select, or as a function like get_size(), but I want them to be accessible as shortcuts, similar to the native backslash commands (\dx, \dt, etc).
So I have used psql's \set feature to store queries/functions as variables, which I will put in the psqlrc file:
`\set size 'select pg_size_pretty(my_size_function(''public''));'`
Then when I type `:size` in psql I would get the size of the "public" schema.
What I want though, is to be able to dynamically pass a schema name, so I could run things like
`:size public`, `:size schema2` etc.
I tried changing the `\set` to: `\set size 'select pg_size_pretty(my_size_function(:schema));'`, but I can only call that by executing `\set schema '''public'''` first.
Since the whole point is to use these universally as shortcuts, having to manually run `\set` commands each time defeats the purpose.
In Oracle the would be colon a bind variable, which would be read at runtime.
How can I do this with psql?

Answer (score 0):

I use these ways.

1. [Postgres Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/xfunc-sql.html) (Inside Postgres CLI)

   ```
   postgres=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getSize(tableName varchar) RETURNS varchar LANGUAGE SQL as
   postgres-# $$
   postgres$#     SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(tableName));
   postgres$# $$;
   CREATE FUNCTION

   postgres=# select getSize('test');
     getsize
   ------------
    8192 bytes
   (1 row)
   ```
2. From Shell (Outside Postgres CLI)

   - `psqlgettablesize(schema, tablename)` - Get table size. Pass `all` for schema argument to get for all schemas.

     ```
     $ psqlgettablesize customer events
             table_name        |     total_size      | table_size  |  index_size
     --------------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------
      test(complete database)  | 19039892127 (18 GB) |             |
      ---------                | ---------           | ---------   | ---------
      customer.events          | 24576 (24 kB)       | 0 (0 bytes) | 24576 (24 kB)
     (3 rows)
     ```
   - `psqlgettablecount(schema, tablename)` - Get count of rows in a table, in a schema

     ```
     $ psqlgettablecount customer events
       count
     ----------
      51850000
     (1 row)
     ```
   - `psqlgetvacuumdetails(schema, tablename)` - Get vacuum details of a table, in a schema

     ```
     $ psqlgetvacuumdetails customer events
      schemaname |  relname  | n_live_tup | n_dead_tup |        last_analyze        | analyze_count |      last_autoanalyze      | autoanalyze_count |        last_vacuum        | vacuum_count | last_autovacuum | autovacuum_count
     ------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------
      customer   |   events  |          0 |          0 | 2019-12-02 18:25:04.887653 |             2 | 2019-11-27 18:49:19.002405 |                 1 | 2019-11-29 13:11:15.92002 |            1 |                 |                0
     (1 row)
     ```
   - `psqltruncatetable(schema, tablename)` - Truncate a table, in a schema, after authorization.

     ```
     $ psqltruncatetable customer events
     Are you sure to truncate table 'customer.events' (y/n)? y
     Time: 4.944 ms
     ```
   - `psqlsettings(category)` - Get settings of Postgres

     ```
     $ psqlsettings Autovacuum
                     name                 |  setting  | unit |  category  |                                        short_desc                                         | extra_desc |  context   | vartype | source  | min_val |  max_val   | enumvals | boot_val  | reset_val | sourcefile | sourceline | pending_restart
     -------------------------------------+-----------+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------
      autovacuum                          | on        |      | Autovacuum | Starts the autovacuum subprocess.                                                         |            | sighup     | bool    | default |         |            |          | on        | on        |            |            | f
      autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor     | 0.1       |      | Autovacuum | Number of tuple inserts, updates, or deletes prior to analyze as a fraction of reltuples. |            | sighup     | real    | default | 0       | 100        |          | 0.1       | 0.1       |            |            | f
     ```
   - `psqlselectrows(schema, tablename)` - Get rows from a table, in a schema

     ```
     $ psqlselectrows customer events
      id | name
     ----+------
       1 | Clicked
       2 | Page Loaded
     (10 rows)
     ```

---

```
#Colors
B_BLACK='\033[1;30m'
B_RED='\033[1;31m'
B_GREEN='\033[1;32m'
B_YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
B_BLUE='\033[1;34m'
B_PURPLE='\033[1;35m'
B_CYAN='\033[1;36m'
B_WHITE='\033[1;37m'
RESET='\033[0m'

#Postgres Command With Params
psqlcommand="$POSTGRES_BIN/psql -U postgres test -q -c"

function psqlgettablesize()
{
    [ -z "$1" ] && echo -e "${B_RED}Argument 1 missing. Schema name needed. ${B_YELLOW}(Pass 'all' to get details from all schema(s)${RESET}" ||
    {
        criteria="and table_schema = '$1'"
        if [ "$1" == "all" ]; then
            criteria=""
        fi

        if [ "$2" != "" ]; then
            criteria+=" and table_name = '$2'"
        fi

        [ -z "$2" ] && echo -e "${B_YELLOW}Table name not given. ${B_GREEN}Showing size of all tables in $1 schema(s)${RESET}"
        query="SELECT
            concat(current_database(), '(complete database)') AS table_name, concat(pg_database_size(current_database()), ' (', pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(current_database())), ')') AS total_size, '' AS table_size, '' AS index_size
        UNION ALL SELECT '---------','---------','---------','---------'
        UNION ALL SELECT
            table_name,
            concat(total_table_size, ' (', pg_size_pretty(total_table_size), ')'),
            concat(table_size, ' (', pg_size_pretty(table_size), ')'),
            concat(index_size, ' (', pg_size_pretty(index_size), ')')
        FROM (
            SELECT
                concat(table_schema, '.', table_name) AS table_name,
                pg_total_relation_size(concat(table_schema, '.', table_name)) AS total_table_size,
                pg_relation_size(concat(table_schema, '.', table_name)) AS table_size,
                pg_indexes_size(concat(table_schema, '.', table_name)) AS index_size
            FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema !~ '^pg_' AND table_schema <> 'information_schema' $criteria ORDER BY total_table_size) AS sizes";
        $psqlcommand "$query"
    }
}
function psqlgettablecount()
{
    [ -z "$1" ] && echo -e "${B_RED}Argument 1 missing: Need schema name${RESET}"
    [ -z "$2" ] && echo -e "${B_RED}Argument 2 missing: Need table name${RESET}" ||
    $psqlcommand "select count(*) from $1.$2;"
}
function psqlgetvacuumdetails()
{
    [ -z "$1" ] && echo -e "${B_RED}Argument 1 missing: Need schema name${RESET}" ||
    [ -z "$2" ] && echo -e "${B_RED}Argument 2 missing: Need table name${RESET}" ||
    $psqlcommand "SELECT schemaname, relname, n_live_tup, n_dead_tup, last_analyze::timestamp, analyze_count, last_autoanalyze::timestamp, autoanalyze_count, last_vacuum::timestamp, vacuum_count, last_autovacuum::timestamp, autovacuum_count FROM pg_stat_user_tables where schemaname = '$1' and relname='$2';"
}
function psqltruncatetable()
{
    [ -z "$1" ] && echo -e "${B_RED}Argument 1 missing: Need schema name${RESET}" ||
    [ -z "$2" ] && echo -e "${B_RED}Argument 2 missing: Need table name${RESET}" ||
    {
        read -p "$(echo -e ${B_YELLOW}"Are you sure to truncate table '$1.$2' (y/n)? "${RESET})" choice
        case "$choice" in
            y|Y ) $psqlcommand "TRUNCATE $1.$2;";;
            n|N ) echo -e "${B_GREEN}Table '$1.$2' not truncated${RESET}";;
            * ) echo -e "${B_RED}Invalid option${RESET}";;
        esac
    }
}
function psqlsettings()
{
    query="select * from pg_settings"
    if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
        query="$query where category like '%$1%'"
    fi
    query="$query ;"
    $psqlcommand "$query"
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo -e "${B_YELLOW}Passing Category as first argument will filter the related settings.${RESET}"
    fi
}
function psqlselectrows()
{
    [ -z "$1" ] && echo -e "${B_RED}Argument 1 missing: Need schema name${RESET}" ||
    [ -z "$2" ] && echo -e "${B_RED}Argument 2 missing: Need table name${RESET}" ||
    $psqlcommand "SELECT * from $1.$2"
}
```

Comment: The idea was that inside psql, the user shouldn't have to type any sql, just a shortcut like `\dx`. The bash solutions are better, but I needed things that can be run in psql itself. A hybrid solution where you use psql \set commands to alias bash commands could be good, like `\set get_table_size '\! psqlgettablesize(:schema,:table)` but it boils down to not being able to dynamically input :schema or :table without first setting it. So it's better to stay in psql completey without calling bash at all, as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to dynamically pass variables so I settled for a system of aliases and variables that work together to provide what I was looking for.     So I can run `:load_schema <schemaname>` and then run commands interacting with the "loaded" schema. Loading a schema is simply aliasing a \set  command. This way people who are unfamiliar with psql can just press `:` and tab autocomplete will show them all of my shortcuts.
All my code is [here](https://github.com/k-caps/db-scripts/tree/master/Postgres/psql-custom-commands).
This isn't exactly what I was looking for so I won't accept it but it's close enough to post in case anyone else wants to do this.